# como colocar fecha por defecto en la fecha ion-datetime ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic-framework, ionic3

tengo muchos problemas con ese formato de fecha de ion-datetime. Solo quiero pasarle el campo date que esta en formato '2017-01-01 04:39:00' a ion-datetime pero me sale error de formato. Llevo varias horas buscando como solucionar esto y no aparece nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaramos la variable y en el constructor la igualamos

```html
  myDate: any ;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.myDate = "2020-12-01";
  }
```

luego en el html

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
```

Resultado 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es cuando intestas una fecha asi

2020-12-01 03:25:00

es decir  yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

yo creería que la mejor opción es manejar las fecha y horas por se parado

Comment: pero como haces por ejemplo para hacer que tome el valor del ngModel

Comment: si te fijas en el imput pone [(ngModel)]="myDate" ese es el nombre de la variable.

la cual le asigno el valor al definirla 

 myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();

Comment: cuando intento hacer new Date("myDate").toISOString() me sale error  Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Invalid time value
RangeError: Invalid time value. pero si le paso directamente "2017-01-01" si me funciona

Comment: lo que pasa es que si no le pongo nada el ngModel no me lo formatea

Comment: ok tu quieres igualar  el texto de el input a una fecha cierto ...  la fecha donde la almacenas ?   o quieres que la fecha sea la fecha de hoy

Comment: la fecha la traigo del modelo. this.requestAngelModel["take_date"]. Tiene el formato "yyyy-mm-dd H:m:s" ejemplo "2020-12-01 03:25:00". Intento igualar la fecha a esa del modelo pero me tira error

Comment: "tu quieres igualar el texto de el input a una fecha cierto ": si eso necesito. Necesito igualar esa fecha del modelo

Comment: hice algunas  pruebas

Comment: al parecer  el problema es la fecha y la hora  al parecer es el formato

Comment: por ejemplo si intentas var fecha = "2030-02-15"; y luego new Date(fecha).toISOString() te saca error. Pero si haces  new Date("2030-02-15").toISOString()  no sale error

Comment: modificare la respuesta con ejemplos para que veas las puebas

Comment: vale quedo atento

Comment: esa respuesta funciono. Me ayudo a entender. Gracias